# What is wrong with this "Do Until" Loop in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to repeat this process x amount of times, but  I keep getting the message "Compile Error: Loop without Do"

Here is my code

```
Do Until x > 10
    x = x + 1
    For Each Row In propertytable
    Range("A2,B2,C2,D2,E2").Select
    Range("E2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Copy to' sheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Property table").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("Copy to' sheet").Select
Loop
```

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: You're missing a `Next Row` before `Loop`

Comment: I suggest you install the [MZ-Tools](http://mztools.com/index.aspx) utility. It will automatically indent your code for you. This makes it easier to spot mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

Indenting your code would've made the omission of `Next Row` more apparent.

```
Do Until x > 10
    x = x + 1
    For Each Row In propertytable
        Range("A2,B2,C2,D2,E2").Select
        Range("E2").Activate
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Copy to' sheet").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Sheets("Property table").Select
        Rows("2:2").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Sheets("Copy to' sheet").Select
    'with indent it's obvious there's something missing
    Next Row
Loop
```

I think you may have some other compile errors in there  that you will find after adding the `Next Row` command.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am having a bit of trouble getting it to compile. I'll keep working on it.